# Checking points in polygons with QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a multi-polygon layer of zip code areas and a point layer of addresses. Both the polygons and the points have a property zip code.
How can I check with QGIS whether there are points in a polygon with a different zip code than that of the polygon? The aim is to detect errors.

Comment: Look at a spatial join of the points to the polygons or an Intersect overlay of the points and polygons.  Then select for zip codes  from the poly layer that differ with the zip codes from the point layer.

Comment: Please explain how to do this, with what function of Qgis.

Comment: In the Processing toolbox look for join attributes by location in the Vector General group or look for the Intersection tool in Vector Overlay.  Click on the help button in the tool input form if you need more info using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Virtual Layer to join the zip code attribute from the intersecting polygon where the zip code doesnt match or where there are no polygon intersecting the point.

Modify the query:

Replace **address** with the name of your point layer, **zip_polygons** with the name of your polygon layer.

The **zip_code** part of **a.zip_code** with the zip code attribute of your point layer. And the **zip_code** part of **b.zip_code** with the zip code attribute of your polygon layer

```sql
SELECT row_number() OVER() AS id, a.geometry
FROM address AS a
LEFT JOIN zip_polygons AS b
ON st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
WHERE a.zip_code <> b.zip_code OR b.zip_code IS NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It took me some time to let it work for me until I found that the two layers had a different CRS.